# How to display multiple data from multiple rows in single row in mysql

Tags: php

I have a table that has multiple rows of data that belongs to individual users.
Eg:

```
            regno         course      score         session     semester
          03/01/02        Mth111       60            2            3
          03/01/02        MTH222       50            2            3
          03/04/05        MTH333       40            2            3
          03/04/05        MTH111       30            2            3
```

I want the values for a particular session and semester to be displayed  in one row per regno in this way:

```
      regno                    
    03/01/02            MTH111         MTH222
                          60             50

   03/04/05             MTH333          MTH111
                          40             30
```

I tried using group by....using a foreach loop with  mysql_fetch_assoc to get the column headers and a group by clause...but only one row showed. How can i resolve this.Thanks.

Comment: You could bodge something together in a query, but it would be painfully fragile. I'd be looking at getting the data and building an array, to then produce a html table from. As soon as one row differs from another sql is going to be very painful. I can give you some clues if you want, but I wouldn't even try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
select regno, concat(course,'\n',score) as someName from table1
```

or

```
select regno, concat(course,'<br>',score) as someName from table1
```

if you are displaying to HTML.

Edit: Righto, I see what you mean now.

```
select regno, group_concat(concat(course, '|', score)) as courses from table1 group by regno
```

Results from [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed555/2)

```
03/01/02    Mth111|60,MTH222|50
03/04/05    MTH333|40,Mth111|30
```

Comment: This will give the same result as what i displayed earlier. I want the regno to appear only once.

Comment: Here is a working [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed555/2) that shows the results

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to pull in these records into a program and format them the way you need to.

This way it will be easier to understand and debug later on.